# video players which support for dot net?

Tags: asp.net

In my application i am going to place a video player that can play the videos .flv extension videos. Present i am using jw player but it is not displaying in fire fox browser, but it playing in IE. can u tell me any player that can play .flv extension videos in both browsers (fire fox and IE).

Comment: `JW Player` works more than fine in FireFox. There must be something wrong with your code.

Comment: no but it is working in IE and it is asking to install flash player, i installed flash player even though it is not working

Comment: Are you using firefox version 3.6.6 or higher?

Comment: it is working fine in IE Mr. Darin

Comment: Also, if your using dot-net, can you consider using Silverlight?.
Simply convert the flv to wmv (or any other format silverlight supports).

Comment: no i am not using silverlight i am using asp.net

Comment: Silverlight can be embeeded in your Asp.net page, just like Flash.
I am suggesting Silverlight because it is essentially dot-net, and it can accomplish playback of videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove firefox,

restart

reinstall

help>update

if it works in IE then it should work in anything!